# Keyboard layout not right for US/UK

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using Windows 10.

I am using a Mac keyboard - both the model I had to replace and the new one are the same.

It's worth noting that if I connect the same keyboard to my laptop running Ubuntu, the behaviour is as I expect. Understandably, that's confusing to me.

I have a UK keyboard, but I need the US layout.
This used to work fine, but I've had to replace it, now it's not quite right anymore.

The usual "candidates" behave correctly:

shift+3: #
(UK would be: £)
Great.

However, the top left (below escape) button isn't right (it used to be!).

No shift produces: \

With shift: |

I expected:

No shift: `

With shift: ~

(That's what I get on the button left of Z), so ISTM those two buttons are flipped.

My language settings are set to
English(United States)
and US(qwerty) layout.

Googling for an image of how a standard US layout should look, I get what I expected, so my years of muscle memory are still correct.

Can anyone help me diagnose or better yet fix this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article
[Making an Apple keyboard work in Windows 10](https://purplecomputing.com/tech-how-to/using-an-apple-keyboard-in-windows/)
advises this procedure:

- Download a bespoke
  [Apple keyboard map for Windows](https://purplecomputing.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/mackbfin.zip)
- Unzip to a folder and execute `setup.exe`
- Open *Settings > Devices > Typing*
- Scroll down and click "Advanced keyboard settings"
- Click the drop-down list below "Override for default input method"
- Select "[English (United Kingdom) – United Kingdom – Mac]"
- If you still encounter wrong keyboard keys, download
  [Microsoft PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) 
  and use Keyboard Manager to map the keys.

References :

- [Windows keys on a Mac keyboard](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/windows-keys-on-a-mac-keyboard-cpmh0152/mac)
- [How to Use a Mac Magic Keyboard on a Windows PC](https://www.lifewire.com/use-magic-keyboard-on-windows-pc-5197318)

Comment: That did it! `~` <- happily typed in the usual way! No need to remap keys for me. Still no idea why I didn't need to do this before, but perhaps I _had_ done that and forgotten. Either way, thanks so much for the help

Comment: Later update: interestingly, connected same keyboard to Win 11 without this issue. So when I seemed to remember not having to do anything before, that's not out of nowhere. Either way, between this answer and do nothing, I seem to be OK ;)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell us on what platform… but generally, one of the big differences between ISO & ANSI is that the key you 'lose' on ANSI isn't the one you'd expect it to be…

Instead, that 'missing' key next to Z actually moves up to be next to 1, & that's the key you lose.

[image]

Comment: d'oh - added that I'm on Windows 10, thank you.

Comment: It's still the same practical effect, just the characters on the keys are different compared to Mac. On Mac, you'd use [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) to swap the characters generated by each key. idk the Win equivalent, sorry.

Comment: So weirdly, the keyboard is as expected when connected to my laptop running Ubuntu. And the same model worked as expected on the same PC before. This is extremely strange

Answer (score 1):

Download Microsoft PowerToys and use the keyboard manager to map the keys

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Thanks - that would've been an option - but I preferred using the approach outlined in the accepted answer